# Way to Deserialize JSON from HttpWebResponse without 3rd party frameworks

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization, datacontractjsonserializer

I'm trying to keep from depending on open source or third party libraries such as Json.NET to parse incoming JSON from an HttpWebResponse.  Why?  Because the more reliance on open source frameworks to aid in your implementations, the more your app has to rely on those dependencies...I don't like my apps to be depenent on a lot of libraries for many reasons if at all possible.  I'm ok with using stuff like Enterprise Library because it's supported by MS but I'm taking more open source libraries.

Anyway, I'm trying to figure out the best way to parse incoming JSON server-side in .NET 3.5.

I know this is going to get a lot of responses and I've even used the .NET 3.5 JavaScriptSerializer to serialize data to JSON but now I'm trying to figure out the best and most simple way to do the reverse without again, having to use a 3rd party / open source framework to aid in this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The **Microsoft** recommended **JSON serializer** is [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770.aspx) This class exists within the **System.Runtime.Serialization** assembly

The sample demonstrates deserializing from JSON data into an object.

```
MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();     
Person p2 = (Person)ser.ReadObject(stream1);
```

To serialize an instance of the Person type to JSON, create the DataContractJsonSerializer first and use the WriteObject method to write JSON data to a stream.

```
Person p = new Person();
//Set up Person object...
MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Person));
ser.WriteObject(stream1, p);
```

**Update:** Added Helper class

Here is a sample helper class that you can use for simple To/From Json serialization:

```
public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static string ToJson<T>(T instance)
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (var tempStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(tempStream, instance);
            return Encoding.Default.GetString(tempStream.ToArray());
        }
    }

    public static T FromJson<T>(string json)
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (var tempStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
        {
            return (T)serializer.ReadObject(tempStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you happen to know when this class was created?  Meaning I wonder if this is a newer framework class than lets say the .NET 3.5 JavaScript serialize.  Because I'd prefer to go with whatever is the latest since it's probably not going to be outdated as soon...if at all.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict, I added a sample helper class that provides both serialization and deserialization.

Comment: where did you see that MS recommends this..I'm on MSDN but do not see that.

Comment: `DataContractJsonSerializer` is newer and came out with .NET 3.5.  The `JavaScriptSerializer` was originally introduced in ASP.NET 1.0 Extensions for ASP.NET 2.0.

Comment: Yes, see that.   I'm just trying to figure out which way to go here basically now.  JavaScriptSerializer vs. the DataContract

Comment: Thanks for the example, it helps a lot in terms of realizing more about the DataJsonSerializer..

Comment: I think you can also use the WebClient object as well to deserialize to a string using the WebClient.DownloadString() method